# how to properly write a benchmark program under release mode?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-construction, profile

while running some benchmark programs, the wall clock may surprisingly give a very small duration, which is because of various compiler optimization like dead code elimination, loop unwinding... that optimize away the tested code.

I may add some "exterior depency" via static/volatile qualifier, but that's not always work.

Any idea?

Comment: just leave it as-is. if you're benchmarking, that's because you want realistic measurements. and compiler optimizations are part of that.

Comment: @H2CO3 That's not entirely true. 3DMark used to do a render test on the CPU, something that is very far from a realistic measurement. The goal of a benchmark is to measure the performance ratios between (usually) hardware. Even if the test is horribly unrealistic, as long as you use the same test all the time you can still compare hardware.

Comment: @Kevin but your result will skew if different hardware handles volitile vs non-volatile with a different ratio and you don't need the volitile

Answer (score 3):

Generally, adding "some "exterior depency" via static/volatile qualifier" will change the actual behavior, and timing so is not advised.

The way I generally make sure that code can be tested is by using `argc` (the first arg to main)
If I need a loop, I change the input data using `argc`.  Also have some dummy calculated value that is dependant on the code and printed after the loops and timer to make sure the result can't be optimized out.

If your fill function can take a seed, you can also just use `argc` as part of the seed.

So if you have random test data, or a loop used to test your code, add `argc` to it.

Without knowing exactly what you are testing the best I can do is someting like

```
seed=argc;        // the compiler cannot count on any value of argc
dummy=0;
total_time=0;
for (rep=0; rep < max_rep; ++rep)
{
    for (i =0; i < max_array; ++i)
    {
         test_array[i]=seed+gen_random();  // Note use of seed
    }

    start=time_now();
    dummy+=function_to_time(test_array);  // this is what you are testing
    end=time_now();
    total_time+=end-start;
    seed++;                               // change seed just to be extra paranoid
}
std::cout << "Time=" << total_time << "  Dummy=" << dummy << std::endl;
```